# MDI childs forms with no free space

Tags: c#, mdi

I want do something like that with MDI but I don't have any idea how. Now I have only childs on cascade mode.

[image]

---

Im back from christmas, from my hometown and start work every day. :)

I necessarily need SuspendLayout and ISupportIntialize?

I dont uderstend how to use SuspendLayout and ISupportIntialize or FixedPanel. So i do this :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wltvd.png

For auto check between 1/2/3/4 panel display mode i try use [select case].

```
       public partial class MainForm : Form
{            
        Child1Form1 Test1 = new Child1Form1();
        Child1Form2 Test2 = new Child1Form2();
        Child1Form3 Test3 = new Child1Form3();
        Child1Form4 Test4 = new Child1Form4();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Show;
        //
        // splitContainer1
        //
        //this.splitContainer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel1;
        this.splitContainer1.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel2;
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(splitContainer2);
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(splitContainer3);
        //
        // splitContainer2
        //
        //this.splitContainer2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer2.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel1;
        this.splitContainer2.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel2;
        this.splitContainer2.Panel1.Controls.Add(Test1);
        this.splitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Add(Test2);
        //
        // splitContainer3
        //
        //splitContainer3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer3.Panel1.Controls.Add(Test3);
        this.splitContainer3.Panel2.Controls.Add(Test4);
        this.Test1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Test2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Test3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Test4.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Test1.Show();
        this.Test2.Show();
        this.Test3.Show();
        this.Test4.Show();
    }
    private void splitContainer1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Test1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Test2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Test3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Test4.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

Comment: propestipes.DOCK but meyby i must combine more, I don't know now.

Comment: Well, clearly you don't want MDI.  WeiFen Luo's DockPanelSuite is popular and has the right price.

Comment: Peter has given an answer that can serve you as inspiration/solution if you are using WinForms. If you use WPF instead of WinForms, let us know...

Comment: I using WinForms. Very thanks guys i check this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it: In the case of ChildForm1-4, add one `SplitContainer` to the form, then add two `SplitContainer`s in each of the panels of the first split container and set `Orientation` to `Horizontal`.  Your `InitializeComponent` method should look something like this when the Designer is done:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        this.splitContainer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        this.splitContainer3 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer2)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer2.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer3)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer3.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // splitContainer1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer2);
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel2
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer3);
        this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(678, 410);
        this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 226;
        this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // splitContainer2
        // 
        this.splitContainer2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer2.Name = "splitContainer2";
        this.splitContainer2.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal;
        this.splitContainer2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(226, 410);
        this.splitContainer2.SplitterDistance = 75;
        this.splitContainer2.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // splitContainer3
        // 
        this.splitContainer3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer3.Name = "splitContainer3";
        this.splitContainer3.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal;
        this.splitContainer3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(448, 410);
        this.splitContainer3.SplitterDistance = 149;
        this.splitContainer3.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(678, 410);
        this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer2)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer2.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer3)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

In the case of ChildForm1-3, add one `SplitContainer` to the form and set `Orientation` to `Horizontal` then add another `SplitContainer` to the top panel and leave the `Orientation` as `Vertical`.  Your `InitializeComponent` method should look something like this when the Designer is done:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        this.splitContainer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer2)).BeginInit();
        this.splitContainer2.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // splitContainer1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
        this.splitContainer1.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal;
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer2);
        this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(678, 410);
        this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 226;
        this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // splitContainer2
        // 
        this.splitContainer2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer2.Name = "splitContainer2";
        this.splitContainer2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(678, 226);
        this.splitContainer2.SplitterDistance = 226;
        this.splitContainer2.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(678, 410);
        this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer2)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```